# How to prevent a Java-process from writing to filesystem?

Tags: java, security-policy

We discovered, that a vendor-provided Java-program, meant to serve files over HTTP(S) -- in response to `GET`-requests -- will *also* happily accept `POST`-requests, creating new files and overwriting existing ones.

While the vendor is dragging its feet with a bugfix, maybe, we can prevent the program from opening new files? It logs to stdout only anyway and has no legitimate need to write anything.

It would still need to be able to open and write to network sockets -- and accept connections -- as well as read files, but not open files for writing.

For operational reasons, it may be easier to give it a customized security policy-file, than to make its directory read-only. Can we craft such a policy-file?

If it matters, we'll need a solution for Java-7, Java-8, and Java-11.

Comment: you can't change java, but you can change the webserver to run as a user who doesn't have write access. what webserver are you using?

Comment: It is the vendor's own implementation. I can't change Java, but I may be able to disable certain functions -- via security policy file. That's my question.

Comment: Until the bug is fixed, I'd run the Java app on an isolated server. That won't prevent writing files, but it would isolate that to just one machine.

Comment: if you look at the process for the application, what user is it running as? is it the logged in user, or a system/service account of some kind?

Comment: *While the vendor is dragging its feet with a bugfix*  Name the vendor?  That'd motivate them...